# Titanum Studio http module not found

Tags: node.js, titanium-mobile

I am trying to use http module in Titanium Studio by

```
var Http = require('http');
```

But when I try to launch the app, it complains the

```
Message: Uncaught Error: Requested module not found: http
```

Did anybody encounter the similar problem? Thanks.

Comment: You can download nodejs sourcecode then copy all file in lib. then clean and run your project.

Answer (score 0):

Titanium is no NodeJS so you don't have access to the NodeJS http-API. Instead, use Ti.Network.createHTTPClient()

Comment: Thanks! But I am still confused, from the following link
[link](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Node.js+Development)

It says “Inside Titanium Studio, Node.js is used for a variety of external tools, including Alloy, the updated SDK command-line interface, and additional products.”

Is there anyway to access the NodeJS API as I am using a third-party SDK that is using the API of NodeJS. Thanks!

Comment: It is meant to say it is used in tooling, the build process.. not to be used in the apps.

You can use https://github.com/smclab/titaniumifier to convert the NPM package of that SDK into a Titanium compatible module. However, this doesn't have a shim for the http module.

If it's a small SDK you could try to shim the parts where it uses the http module yourself.